# How do I set up Deployer to sync only specified folders from localhost to production?

Tags: laravel, php-deployer

I have a localhost Laravel project I want to deploy with Deployer. Currently I do it manually using an FTP tool and only sync the app, resources folders and seems to work just fine.

I want to use Deployer or some other tool I can run from terminal to sync or upload new files to the server.

Can someone help with a recipe or advice?
Do I need rsync setup using deployer or is there a way to do it without recipe/rsync.php?

Here are the steps I want configured(for now):

- connect to the server, I have ssh access and I can probably configure a key
- setup the 2 3 folders I want to sync, as well as files that need to be ignored.

These seem like simple tasks but for some reason I have a hard time setting them up.

Thank you

Comment: Consider using Ansible, it a nice tool for provisioning servers and much more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this questions is still pending for answer, but one alternative is using some versioning tool like git, you only watch some folders and ignore the remaining. and with the basic recipe you can deploy a github/gilab/bitbucket project.

A more in dept explanation on this topic can be found [enter link description here]here[1](https://alibaba-cloud.medium.com/automating-your-php-application-deployment-with-php-deployer-b00c1dc64d4a).